# Windows subsystem for Android home directory location

Tags: android, windows-11

I'm looking to find a file I downloaded on Windows subsystem for Android, and I was wondering where the folder is located? I know for Ubuntu for Windows the folder is:

`%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState`

However, I can't find the directory for Android.

Comment: At this current time you have to use Android Debug Bridge (adb).  At that point you can likely use SFTP to transfer files between the host and the WSA

Comment: You should also avoid modifying files by navigating to `%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState` when dealing with WSL as that is NOT a supported method to view files within your WSL instance.

Comment: I was trying to avoid SFTP, it's a pretty large file but I don't see any other way. Maybe I can rar it and break it down to smaller parts... Thanks for the WSL tip, I'll look into it

Comment: You can use ADP to transfer the file.  Internal transfer speeds between a host and a VM even with SFTP/ADP would match the transfer speeds of a file copy operation.  You are basically opening a SFTP/ADP connection between the same machine.  In the end it's not currently possible to view the files like you can with  `\\wsl.localhost ` with WSL

Comment: Here is a trick that I use (for exploration ONLY).  Open "something" that is running under the subsystem.  Open the system internals process explorer.  Look at the open file handles.  @Ramhound is very correct though.. although I have never had a problem *reading* files under WSL, if you touch them (as in write in any way) you will screw up the metadata windows uses to manage windows/linux differences and hose the file.  You will not be happy and it is a crap shoot if a tool you are using will actually try to re-write a file that shouldn't be touched.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at here

```
C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Packages\MicrosoftCorporationII.WindowsSubsystemForAndroid_8wekyb3d8bbwe
```

Answer (score 1):

There is another way to access individual files: You can actually send files from Windows Subsystem for Android by sharing the file with Windows in an app. It is then saved in the Downloads folder.[image: share screenshot]

Comment: This is helpful but it doesn't work for all files. I couldn't get it to work with a .crt file but it did work with a .apk file. Those are the only two files I tested with.

Answer (score 1):

This is far easier ...
you just need any file explorer in android with the (access from ftps)
start ftps service and access it from your Windows folder by typing the address
for example : ftps://192.168.130.401:8080

Comment: You answered half the question. I was able to get the file I needed which is exactly what I was trying to accomplish but I still want to know the folder directory. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

This is the site that I have used for instructions:
[https://allthings.how/how-to-transfer-files-to-wsa-storage-on-windows-11/#:~:text=For%20example%2C%20if%20you%20want%20to%20transfer%20the,ADB%20push%20command%20syntax%20to%20copy%20the%20files](https://allthings.how/how-to-transfer-files-to-wsa-storage-on-windows-11/#:%7E:text=For%20example%2C%20if%20you%20want%20to%20transfer%20the,ADB%20push%20command%20syntax%20to%20copy%20the%20files).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1179330)